# Re-write chart.js functionality in ng2-charts

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm new to Chart.js and ng2-charts. I want this functionality in chart.js to be re-written in ng2-charts.  Is it even possibe?

```
Chart.defaults.LineWithLine = Chart.defaults.line;
Chart.controllers.LineWithLine = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  draw: function(ease) {
     Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);

     if (this.chart.tooltip._active && this.chart.tooltip._active.length) {
      var activePoint = this.chart.tooltip._active[0],
          ctx = this.chart.ctx,
          x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
          topY = this.chart.scales['y-axis-0'].top,
          bottomY = this.chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;

       // draw line
       ctx.save();
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
       ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
       ctx.lineWidth = 2;
       ctx.strokeStyle = '#07C';
       ctx.stroke();
       ctx.restore();
     }
  }
});
```

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/haq5k2mw/

Answer (score 2):

You can use clipboardjs instead

Download it: https://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/

You can use this method now: (require jquery)

In your html head add:

```
<script src="dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```

In your html code add:

```
<pre class="copytoclipboard">
    <code class="language-html">
        <h1>Hello world !</h1>
    </code>
</pre>
```

In your page footer add:

```
<script>
        /* Prism copy to clipbaord for all pre with copytoclipboard class */
        $('pre.copytoclipboard').each(function () {
            $this = $(this);
            $button = $('<button>Copy</button>');
            $this.wrap('<div/>').removeClass('copytoclipboard');
            $wrapper = $this.parent();
            $wrapper.addClass('copytoclipboard-wrapper').css({position: 'relative'})
            $button.css({position: 'absolute', top: 10, right: 10}).appendTo($wrapper).addClass('copytoclipboard btn btn-default');
            /* */
            var copyCode = new Clipboard('button.copytoclipboard', {
                target: function (trigger) {
                    return trigger.previousElementSibling;
                }
            });
            copyCode.on('success', function (event) {
                event.clearSelection();
                event.trigger.textContent = 'Copied';
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    event.trigger.textContent = 'Copy';
                }, 2000);
            });
            copyCode.on('error', function (event) {
                event.trigger.textContent = 'Press "Ctrl + C" to copy';
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    event.trigger.textContent = 'Copy';
                }, 2000);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Based on: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/copy-to-clipboard-made-easy-with-clipboardjs--cms-25086